# cannot figure out why the error page gets triggered

Tags: php, forms, phpmailer

Why does `unexpectedReserveError.html` get triggered? As the code stands, does that mean the session token are not matching? I'm super bad at PHP ...

**EDIT**

Adding a description of the problem. As this code stands, it works fine for its purposes, ie, there's a htm form (second code set), and that transmits its variables to the backend page (first code set). What is puzzling to me is that the error page randomly happens. And a lot of people complain that the error page pops up, and thus abandon the page.

I've only been able to trigger the error page once, and only once, and even with that, there were no obvious clues why that happened. Thus my question on top is that .. since if you look at the code, you can see that there is a session token matching which if it doesn't work, it triggers the `unexpectedReserveError.html` page? (there are two error pages, the `header('location: URL/reserveError.html');` & `header('location: URL/unexpectedReserveError.html');`

Bottom line, I'm trying to figure out under what circumstances the unexpectedReserveError page is getting triggered because it's causing problems.

**BackendPage**

```
<?php

session_start();

  if ($_POST['token'] == $_SESSION['token']) {

        foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if(ini_get('magic_quotes_gpc'))
          $_POST[$key] = stripslashes($_POST[$key]);
          $_POST[$key] = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST[$key]));
    }



                    $nights = $_POST['nights']; 
                    $arrivals = $_POST['arrivals'];
                    $male = $_POST['male']; 
                    $female = $_POST['female']; 
                    $rooms = $_POST['rooms']; 
                    $type = $_POST['type']; 
                    $name = $_POST['name']; 
                    $address = $_POST['address']; 
                    $zip = $_POST['zip']; 
                    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; 
                    $email = $_POST['email_again']; 
                    $cell = $_POST['cell']; 
                    $message = $_POST['message']; 
                    $date = $_POST['date'];

                    require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

                  $mail = new PHPMailer;
                  $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
                  $mail->isSMTP();  
                  //$mail->SMTPDebug = 4; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
                  $mail->Host = 'tls://smtp.gmail.com:587'; // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
                  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
                  $mail->Username = '';                 // SMTP username
                  $mail->Password = ''; 
                  $mail->addReplyTo( '', 'Hotel' );
                  $mail->AddCC('', 'Hotel');
                  $mail->addAddress(  $email, $first_name );
                  $mail->SetFrom('', '');
                  $mail->isHTML(true);                             
  // Set email format to HTML

                    $mail->Subject = 'Hotel Room Request';


                    $mail->Body = "<table width='600'><tr><td colspan='2' height='20'><p style='text-align:center; font-size:20px; color:#ddd; padding:0px; margin:0px;'>Copy of Your Reserve Form</p></td></tr>"
                                  ."<tr><td colspan='2'  height='80' width='600'><p style='color:#d1502d;font-size:50px;text-align:center;padding:0px; margin:0px;'>Hotel</p></td></tr>"
                                                ."<tr><td colspan='2'  height='60' width='600' style='text-align:center; color:#606060;font-size:20px;padding:0px; margin:0px;'>Los Angeles, CA </td></tr>"
                                                ."<tr><td colspan='2'  height='30' width='600' style='text-align:center;'><h3 style='color:#d1502d; '>Come and Explore  Los Angeles</h3></td></tr>"
                                                ."<tr><td height='20' width='300'><p style='font-size:20px; color:gray; padding:10px; margin:0px; text-align:right;'>Your Number of Nights: </p></td><td height='20' width='300'> <p style='font-size:20px; color:gray; padding:10px; margin:0px;'>$nights</p></td></tr>"
                                                ."<tr><td height='20' width='300'><p style='font-size:20px; color:gray; padding:10px; margin:0px; text-align:right;'>Your Arrival Time: </p></td><td height='20' width='300'><p style='font-size:20px; color:gray; padding:10px; margin:0px;'>$arrivals</p></td></tr>"
                                                ."<tr><td height='20' width='300'><p style='font-size:20px; color:gray; padding:10px; margin:0px; text-align:right;'>Date:</p></td><td height='20' width='300'><p style='font-size:20px; color:gray; padding:0px; margin:10px;'> $date</p></td></tr>"
                                                ."<tr><td height='20' width='300'><p style='font-size:20px; color:gray; padding:10px; margin:0px; text-align:right;'>Number of Guests - (Gender: male): </p></td><td height='20' width='300'><p style='font-size:20px; color:gray; padding:10px; margin:0px;'>$male</p></td></tr>"
                                                ."<tr><td height='20' width='300'><p style='font-size:20px; color:gray; padding:10px; margin:0px; text-align:right;'>Number of Guests - (Gender: female):</p></td><td height='20' width='300'><p style='font-size:20px; color:gray; padding:0px; margin:10px;'> $female</p></td></tr>"
                                                ."<tr><td height='20' width='300'><p style='font-size:20px; color:gray; padding:10px; margin:0px; text-align:right;'>Number of Rooms:</p></td><td height='20' width='300'><p style='font-size:20px; color:gray; padding:0px; margin:10px;'> $rooms</p></td></tr>"
                                                ."<tr><td height='20' width='300'><p style='font-size:20px; color:gray; padding:10px; margin:0px; text-align:right;'>Type of Room:</p></td><td height='20' width='300'><p style='font-size:20px; color:gray; padding:0px; margin:10px;'> $type</p></td></tr>"
                                                ."<tr><td height='20' width='300'><p style='font-size:20px; color:gray; padding:10px; margin:0px; text-align:right;'>Your Name:</p></td><td height='20' width='300'><p style='font-size:20px; color:gray; padding:0px; margin:10px;'> $name</p></td></tr>"
                                                ."<tr><td height='20' width='300'><p style='font-size:20px; color:gray; padding:10px; margin:0px; text-align:right;'>Your Address:</p></td><td height='20' width='300'><p style='font-size:20px; color:gray; padding:0px; margin:10px;'> $address</p></td></tr>"
                                                ."<tr><td height='20' width='300'><p style='font-size:20px; color:gray; padding:10px; margin:0px; text-align:right;'>Your Zip:</p></td><td height='20' width='300'><p style='font-size:20px; color:gray; padding:0px; margin:10px;'> $zip</p></td></tr>"
                                                ."<tr><td height='20' width='300'><p style='font-size:20px; color:gray; padding:10px; margin:0px; text-align:right;'>Your Telephone:</p></td><td height='20' width='300'><p style='font-size:20px; color:gray; padding:0px; margin:10px;'> $telephone</p></td></tr>"
                                                ."<tr><td height='20' width='300'><p style='font-size:20px; color:gray; padding:10px; margin:0px; text-align:right;'>Your Cell:</p></td><td height='20' width='300'><p style='font-size:20px; color:gray; padding:0px; margin:10px;'> $cell</p></td></tr>"
                                                ."<tr><td height='20' width='300'><p style='font-size:20px; color:gray; padding:10px; margin:0px; text-align:right;'>Your Email:</p></td><td height='20' width='300'><p style='font-size:20px; color:gray; padding:0px; margin:10px;'> $email</p></td></tr>"
                                                ."<tr><td height='20' width='300'><p style='font-size:20px; color:gray; padding:10px; margin:0px; text-align:right;'>Your Message:</p></td><td height='20' width='300'><p style='font-size:20px; color:gray; padding:0px; margin:10px;'> $message</p></td></tr>"
                                                ."<tr><td colspan='2'  height='15' width='600'><p style=' text-align:center;padding:0px; margin:0px;'><a style='color:#d1502d;font-size:15px;text-align:center;padding:0px; margin:0px;text-decoration:none;'href='url'>Visit Our Site</a></p></td></tr></table>";


                    $mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!';

                    if(!$mail->send()) {
                        header('location: URL/reserveError.html');

                    } else {
                        header('location: URL/reserveResult.html');

                    }

    }

    else {
            header('location: URL/unexpectedReserveError.html');
    }
```

**This is the html form page:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
  <title>Hotel</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/default.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/default.date.css">  
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style type="text/css">
    .error {
      color:red;
    }
    body {
      padding-top: 146px;
      padding-top:175px;
    }
    .language_choice_english {
      padding-right: 1%
    }

    .language_choice_japanese {
        padding-right: 3%;
    }
  </style>
</head>


<body>

    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="js/additional-methods.js"></script>
      <script> 
          $(document).ready(function () {

              $('#reserveForm').validate({ 
                  rules: {
                      name: {
                          required: true
                      },
                      address: {
                          required: true
                      },
                      zip: {
                        required: true
                      },
                      telephone: {
                        required: true
                      },
                      email: {
                        required: true
                      },
                      email_again: {
                        equalTo: "#cemail"
                      },
                      nights: {
                        required: true
                      },
                      arrivals: {
                        required: true
                      },
                      male: {
                        required: true
                      },
                      female: {
                        required: true
                      },
                      rooms: {
                        required: true
                      },
                      type: {
                        required: true
                      },
                      date: {
                        required: true
                      }
                  }
              });
          });
      </script>
</head>
<body>

<?php
session_start(); //allows use of session variables

if (!isset($_SESSION['token']) && $_SESSION['token'] == $_POST['token']) {

  $token = base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32));
  $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
}

else {
  $token = base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32));
  $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
}


?>


  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <a class="brand pull-left" href="index.html">
            <img id="Logo" src="./images/logo.gif" alt="Hotel">
            </a>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
       <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><span id="overall_title">Hotel</span><small id="description_of_city">Los Angeles</small></a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="rooms.html">Rooms & information</a></li>
        <li><a href="reserve.php">Book to Reserve</a></li>
        <li><a href="location.html">Location Info</a></li>
        <li><a href="additional.html">Additional Info</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <p class="pull-right language_choice_english"><a href="reserve.php">English</a></p>
        <p class="pull-right language_choice_japanese"><a href="reserve-ja.php"><span lang="ja">日本語</span></a></p>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

<div id="main-container" class="col-xs-12">


  <form class="form-horizontal"  method="POST" action="bookInformation.php" id="reserveForm" autocomplete="off">

 <p><a href="rules.html" target="_blank">Rules and Regulations of  Hotel</a></p>

            <div>
            <label>* Required fields</label>
            </div>


            <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>" />


            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="cnights" class="col-sm-2 control-label">* Number of Nights</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
              <select id="cnights" class="form-control" name="nights">                 
                <option value="">Number of Nights</option>
                <option <?php if ($nights == 1 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="1">1</option>
                <option <?php if ($nights == 2 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="2">2</option>
                <option <?php if ($nights == 3 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="3">3</option>
                <option <?php if ($nights == 4 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="4">4</option>
                <option <?php if ($nights == 5 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="5">5</option>
                <option <?php if ($nights == 6 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="6">6</option>
                <option <?php if ($nights == 7 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="7">7</option>
                <option <?php if ($nights == 8 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="8">8</option>
                <option <?php if ($nights == 9 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="9">9</option>
                <option <?php if ($nights == 10 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="10">10</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="carrivals" class="col-sm-2 control-label">* Time of Arrival</label>
               <div class="col-sm-10">
              <select id="carrivals" class="form-control" name="arrivals">
                <option value="">Time of Arrival</option>
                <option <?php if ($arrivals == 14 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="14">14</option>
                <option <?php if ($arrivals == 15 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="15">15</option>
                <option <?php if ($arrivals == 16 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="16">16</option>
                <option <?php if ($arrivals == 17 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="17">17</option>
                <option <?php if ($arrivals == 18 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="18">18</option>
                <option <?php if ($arrivals == 19 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="19">19</option>
                <option <?php if ($arrivals == 20 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="20">20</option>
                <option <?php if ($arrivals == 21 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="20">21</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="cdate" class="col-sm-2 control-label">* Check-In Date</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input class="datepicker" type="text" placeholder="Please pick a date" id="cdate" name="date">
              </div>
          </div>


           <div class="form-group">
              <label for="cmale" class="col-sm-2 control-label">* Number of People</label>
               <div class="col-sm-10">
              <select id="cmale" class="form-control" name="male">
                <option value="">Gender Male</option>
                <option <?php if ($male === 0 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="0">0</option>
                <option <?php if ($male == 1 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="1">1</option>
                <option <?php if ($male == 2 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="2">2</option>
                <option <?php if ($male == 3 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="3">3</option>
                <option <?php if ($male == 4 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="4">4</option>
                <option <?php if ($male == 5 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="5">5</option>
                <option <?php if ($male == 6 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="6">6</option>
                <option <?php if ($male == 7 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="7">7</option>
                <option <?php if ($male == 8 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="8">8</option>
                <option <?php if ($male == 9 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="9">9</option>
                <option <?php if ($male == 10 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="10">10</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">* Number of People</label>
               <div class="col-sm-10">
              <select class="form-control" name="female">
                <option value="">Gender Female</option>
                <option <?php if ($female === 0 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="0">0</option>
                <option <?php if ($female == 1 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="1">1</option>
                <option <?php if ($female == 2 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="2">2</option>
                <option <?php if ($female == 3 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="3">3</option>
                <option <?php if ($female == 4 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="4">4</option>
                <option <?php if ($female == 5 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="5">5</option>
                <option <?php if ($female == 6 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="6">6</option>
                <option <?php if ($female == 7 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="7">7</option>
                <option <?php if ($female == 8 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="8">8</option>
                <option <?php if ($female == 9 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="9">9</option>
                <option <?php if ($female == 10 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="10">10</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            </div>




            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">* Number of Rooms</label>
               <div class="col-sm-10">
              <select class="form-control" name="rooms">
                <option value="">Number of Rooms</option>
                <option <?php if ($rooms == 1 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="1">1</option>
                <option <?php if ($rooms == 2 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="2">2</option>
                <option <?php if ($rooms == 3 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="3">3</option>
                <option <?php if ($rooms == 4 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="4">4</option>
                <option <?php if ($rooms == 5 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="5">5</option>
                <option <?php if ($rooms == 6 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="6">6</option>
                <option <?php if ($rooms == 7 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="7">7</option>
                <option <?php if ($rooms == 8 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="8">8</option>
                <option <?php if ($rooms == 9 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="9">9</option>
                <option <?php if ($rooms == 10 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="10">10</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">* Type of Room</label>
               <div class="col-sm-10">
              <select class="form-control" name="type">
                <option value="">Type of Room</option>
                <option <?php if ($type == B ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="B">B</option>
                <option <?php if ($type == C ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="C">C</option>
                <option <?php if ($type == D ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="D">D</option>
                <option <?php if ($type == E ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="E">E</option>
                <option <?php if ($type == F ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="F">F</option>
                <option <?php if ($type == G ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="G">G</option>
                <option <?php if ($type == H ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="H">H</option>
                <option <?php if ($type == I ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="I">I</option>
                <option <?php if ($type == J ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="J">J</option>
                <option <?php if ($type == K ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="K">K</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="cname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">* Name</label>
             <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Name" id="cname" type="text" name="name" value="<?php if(isset($name)) { echo $name; }?>">
              </div>
        </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="caddress" class="col-sm-2 control-label">* Address</label>
                 <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input class="form-control" id="caddress" placeholder="Address" type="text" name="address" value="<?php if(isset($address)) { echo $address; }?>">
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="czip" class="col-sm-2 control-label">* Zip</label>
                 <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input id="czip" class="form-control" placeholder="Zip" type="text" name="zip" value="<?php if(isset($zip)) { echo $zip; }?>">
              </div>
            </div>


           <div class="form-group">
                <label for="ctelephone" class="col-sm-2 control-label">* Telephone Number</label>
                 <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input id="ctelephone" class="form-control" placeholder="Telephone Number" type="text" name="telephone" value="<?php if(isset($zip)) { echo $zip; }?>">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="ccellphonenumber" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Cell Phone Number</label>
                 <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input id="ccellphonenumber" class="form-control" placeholder="Cell Phone Number" type="text" name="cell" value="<?php if(isset($cell)) { echo $cell; }?>">
              </div>
            </div>



            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="cemail" class="col-sm-2 control-label">* Email</label>
                 <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input id="cemail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" type="text" name="email">
              </div>
            </div>

           <div class="form-group">
                <label for="cemail" class="col-sm-2 control-label">* Email Address Confirmation</label>
                 <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input id="cemail2" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" type="text" name="email_again">
              </div>
            </div>


          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Message</label>
             <div class="col-sm-10">
             <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="message" value="<?php if(isset($message)) { echo $message; }?>"></textarea>
           </div>
          </div>


    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>      

</form>

</div>


  <footer class="col-xs-12 roomsFooter">  

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">2015  Hotel -- All rights reserved</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">Terms of Use</div>
       <div class="col-md-4">Facebook / Twitter / Instagram </div>
    </div>  
  </footer>

<script src="js/picker.js"></script>
<script src="js/picker.date.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.datepicker').pickadate();
});
</script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**

**Session Token Stuff from Second Code Set Above**

```
<?php
session_start(); //allows use of session variables

if (!isset($_SESSION['token']) && $_SESSION['token'] == $_POST['token']) {

  $token = base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32));
  $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
}

else {
  $token = base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32));
  $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
}


?>
```

And this: `<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>" />`

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: @FrankerZ, will do. Thank you. I was hoping someone could see at a glance any glaring problems right away. But will add the elaboration on top right now.

Comment: @FrankerZ, added the description of the problem. If it's confusing, please let me know, or clarify further.

Comment: try (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#gmail-oauth2-and-allow-less-secure-apps) it says, this will usually solve the problem for PHPMailer.

Comment: @dadan ... hm ... you don't see any problems with my code? ... can't believe I'm hoping it's rather my code that PHPMailers' mail server issues ... can't troubleshoot it right now anyway as I'm at home ... but I am using Gmail STMP mail server ... and I've already allowed `"Allow less secure apps"` part and `tls` encryption as you can see from php code above ... I'm really bad at PHP ... not sure how else to troubleshoot this problem.

Comment: @dadan, also, worth noting is that this problem gets triggered intermittently ... not consistently ...

Comment: Just read the code - the only way you can get to `unexpectedReserveError` is if `$_POST['token'] == $_SESSION['token']` is not true. It's nothing to do with the rest of your code.

Comment: @Synchro, thank you! Figured that out ... now it's a matter of rewriting the `$_POST['token'] == $_SESSION['token']` part, correct? I finally realized that it happens on the first try when you open a browser (any), and go to their reserve page, and try to submit it ... then the `unexpectedReserveError` page happens ... but if you try to resubmit again, it works fine ... I'll post it as another question within an hour ... but if you have any helpful advice ... it would be much appreciated.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the comparison, you just need to figure out why those values are not in `$_POST` or `$_SESSION` if you're expecting them to be, which probably happens on other pages.

Comment: @Synchro, well, it seems that those values appear after you submit it the second time, third time, etc ... but not the first time (ie, it triggers the error page) ... and that's what is puzzling me ...

Comment: @Synchro, I just took out the token session stuff from the second code set to make it easier to read ... do you see anything wrong with, ie, why it doesn't seem to set the first time you submit the page?

Comment: @Synchro, have written it up as a new question as it's a different problem as opposed to this current question ... if you can troubleshoot it, and post an answer to the other question, please do feel free to do so =) ... here's the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38794913/session-token-not-setting-the-first-time